# Datatype of date in elastic search

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

error:
Caused by: org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Could not write all entries for bulk operation [1/1]. Error sample (first [5] error messages):
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: mapper_parsing_exception: failed to parse field [user_first_updated] of type [date] in document with id 'BcivPIkBruqga4Hh9x2u'. Preview of field's value: '2023-07-09 17:54:01.761';org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: illegal_argument_exception: failed to parse date field [2023-07-09 17:54:01.761] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSZ];org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: date_time_parse_exception: Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers
{"index":{}}
{"tenant_id":"KAR1234","username":"bsqlcfg0","learned":false,"user_first_updated":"2023-07-09 17:54:01.761","user_last_updated":"2023-07-09 22:00:00.000","target_table":"user_learning_stats"}

Bailing out...
mapping in elastic search
"user_first_updated": {
"format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSZ",
"type": "date"
},

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add in date the separator 'T', "user_first_updated":"2023-07-09T17:54:01.761". Looks the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats).

Comment: if time is added, there must be a timezone indicated also. `Z` is used to indicate UTC and this should be used at all times to avoid problems of second guessing or assuming timezone of the client and server